# JBoss frees after I set the server configuration name to production (jboss-eap-5.2)

Tags: jboss

JBoss eap 5.2 frees when I set the server configuration to run as production. The last message I received is:
10:55:46,699 WARN  [XMLAttributePersistenceManager] no protocol: data/xmbean-attrs... Reverting to home dir relative path '/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production'

I am using run-sh script to start JBoss as following:

cd /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/bin

./run.sh -c production

=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss

JAVA: /opt/java/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -server -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

CLASSPATH: /opt/jboss/bin/run.jar:/opt/java/lib/tools.jar

```
=========================================================================

10:55:33,616 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
10:55:33,617 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [EAP] 5.2.0 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_2_0 date=201211232041)
10:55:33,617 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
10:55:33,618 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as
10:55:33,618 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/
10:55:33,618 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/lib/
10:55:33,619 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/common/
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/common/lib/
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: production
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/conf/
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production
10:55:33,620 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/data
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/lib/
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/log
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/tmp/native
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/tmp
10:55:33,621 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/tmp/deploy
10:55:35,103 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/conf/bootstrap.xml
10:55:35,717 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
10:55:35,720 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
10:55:36,072 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: /opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production/tmp
10:55:36,073 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
10:55:38,025 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_24,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:55:38,026 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b24)
10:55:38,026 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 20.0-b12,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:55:38,026 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64,amd64
10:55:38,028 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/jboss/lib/endorsed 
10:55:38,126 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
10:55:42,145 INFO  [PropertyEditorManagerService] Registered editor class org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertiesEditor for class java.util.Properties
10:55:46,699 WARN  [XMLAttributePersistenceManager] no protocol: data/xmbean-attrs... Reverting to home dir relative path '/opt/jboss-eap-5.2/jboss-as/server/production'
```

Please help

Comment: Actually, JBoss starts fine when I check the production/log/server.log
But I don't know why the console frees. Is that normal ?

Comment: Maybe you have disabled console log? Then you will not see more log at that point in the console and logging continues to the file.